# A proof related to beta and gamma distribution

Tags: gamma-distribution

[image]

Please help me to solve the above proof. It is related to beta and gamma function .

Comment: I voted to close this question as it does not produce any argument as to why the OP is stuck.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint**. One may try
$$
x=\sin^2 \theta,\qquad dx=2 \cos \theta \sin \theta \:d\theta.
$$